# Spring RabbitMQ Connection and Resource Management Issues

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I need to consume messages from Rabbit HA cluster via HAProxy so I switched to `CacheMode.CONNECTION` as it is recommended in [spring-amqp-documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#connections). Moreover I need to consume messages from many queues so I create for each queue `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` with 4 concurrent consumers and I have few questions:

1. After few tests it looks that my approach is not efficient because each time when a new queue is added also new SimpleMessageListenerContainer is created with 4 threads. So I could set more queues for the given `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` what looks more efficient but maybe there is another better way?
2. Why when I have switched to `CacheMode.CONNECTION` for each consumer in `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` is created new connection? Can I set in some way one connection for all consumers in a given `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` or maybe it is not recommended?
3. How to handle exception

   > "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AutoRecoverConnectionNotCurrentlyOpenException:
   >   Auto recovery connection is not currently open"

   I received it when one RabbitMQ node is down. Even when node is up again `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` cannot reconnect.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The upcoming 2.0 release has a new `DirectMessageListenerContainer` that shares threads across containers [documentation here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/_reference.html#choose-container).
   The `2.0.0.M4` milestone is available now; the GA release is expected to be mid July.
2. If you want a single connection per container use the default cache mode and a separate connection factory for each container.
3. Disable the client's connection factory auto recovery mechanism; it is enabled by default in the 4.x client; Spring AMQP has its own recovery mechanism that will generally recover faster. Since version 1.7.1 Spring AMQP disables it by default, unless you configure your own Rabbit ConnectionFactory.